# Angular $uibmodal close and submit

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Hello I'm new to angularjs and am exploring the functionality of $uibmodal.  I was able to get $uibmodal.open to operate, but with an error that is occuring that I don't understand.  My $uibmodal.close is not functioning at the moment and when I use $uibmodal.submit, instead of adding on to my current array it resets the page.  If anyone can give me a tip to get proper functionality that would be great.  Thanks.
[Here is my Github repository](https://github.com/bjm8498/bloc-chat-project/tree/Checkpoint-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try with this

```
    modalInstance.close('resetModel');
```

Answer (score 2):

First up is *how to use this site*. One should be able to understand the question without going to external sources. Linking to a github repo is great, but you need to post code here as well. Mostly because the repo is likely to change and what good is this question to anyone then?

Secondly, I'm not sure there is such a thing as a $uibModal.submit(), so you have to tell us where you got that from. But I'm guessing you are triggering something like a form submit which by default reloads the page; In angular you almost never want to reload the page.

Next up is this:

```
modal.close = function () {
    $uibModal.close(/* Something missing here */ );
};
```

You likely want to return something here if you want the modal to affect anything outside the modal. From the docs: *The result must be passed in this format:* `{$value: myResult}`

And finally:

```
var mobalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    templateUrl : '/templates/modals.html',
    controller: 'ModalCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'modal'
});
```

This is good and all for generating a modal instance, but you'll need something to handle the response (the value it returns when closed) as well. In `modalInstance.result` you'll find a promise, meaning you can access it using `.then(successHandler, errorHandler)`. It'll be called when the modal closes. For example (from the docs):

```
modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
    $ctrl.selected = selectedItem;
}, function () {
    $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
});
```

Here `selectedItem` is the value returned from the modal, and `$ctrl.selected` is a property in the controller that opened the modal.

Comment: There are other issues I have with the code as well. I think having a `ModalController` and a `ModalInstanceController` is confusing to say the least. Notice the angular.ui demo they use `ModalDemoController`. Meaning you are better off calling it `PageCtrl` or `SomesectionCtrl`or using your `RoomCtrl`.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  This is an assignment from school I've been stuck on it for about 3 weeks now.  There are so many different parts to the project I didn't know how to incorporate all of it together without linking to a branch from the project.  I've never worked with all of these moving parts before, so next time should I link all the files to the page?  I didn't know whether to link the project or just to throw just parts into the question because I wanted to make sure people would see what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Add the things you think are relevant, and edit in more if someone asks. Good luck with your project!